# Impedance matching

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance, impedance-matching, microwave

I am a newbie at microwave. I'm confused about impedance matching. So far just 50 Ω impedance stub in outside.

[image]

But in this example below I saw 75 Ω. I could use the Smith Chart but I didn't know how to solve this. Can anyone give me a clue about this?

The question is simply: How can I arrange 75 Ω? Short stub and open stub; both solutions are the same case?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are unsure of. Impedance matching isn't a microwave phenomenon by the way. Your question is *How can I arrange 75 ohm?* and this isn't really a sufficient enough question to be able to answer.

Comment: Try this http://amanogawa.com/archive/DoubleStub/DoubleStub-2.html